# PHP not able to connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, php

I just compiled PHP 7.0.4 on a Fedora 23 box, created a test script to connect to MySQL on localhost and all I get is:

```
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: 2002 Debugging error: No such file or directory
```

According to PHP that is because PHP cannot find /tmp/mysql.sock, the file does exist, so I reconfigured MySQL and PHP to have them both point to the same file, without success, this is what /tmp shows about mysql.sock:

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root    25 Mar 21 10:13 mysql.sock -> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

I don't know what to do at this point, because when I change the script to connect to 127.0.0.1, it works just fine.

Others at stackoverflow told me to post this here to see if I can get more help, because there is nothing wrong with the code I'm using to connect.
(Related Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065587/php-not-seeing-mysql-sock-from-the-web)

Finally, my Firewall is masked and my selinux is disabled and I also tested it from the console and it works, it doesn't work only via web even though phpinfo() shows this.

```
mysqli.default_socket   /tmp/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Could you do a `dig localhost` and post results?

Comment: `so I reconfigured MySQL and PHP to have them both point to the same file`. Can you post both `php.ini` and `my.cnf`?

Comment: my.cnf has this: "socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock" and php.ini has this: "mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock" also my mysqld.service has "PrivateTmp=false"

Comment: dig localhost showed me this: "localhost.  600 IN A 127.0.0.1"

Comment: Use strace on the process and see what happens.

Comment: I ran strace and it showed me that it couldn't find snmp.conf which is not /tmp/mysql.sock I'm installing net-snmp now to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Why did you change the location of the MySQL socket?

Comment: I didn't, I just created a symbolic link at /tmp pointing to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, the weird part is when I do a fsockopen to that same socket file PHP does open it, so if PHP can open it and the path is configured correctly on both, why does PHP keep giving me that message even when via console it runs just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out when I built PHP I did not include --with-mysql-sock=/path/to/mysq.sock, so even though it was set in php.ini it did not know where to find it, once I included that it worked.

Thanks for your help everybody.